# Flutter work manager not working properly to execute function that resets state on a daily basis

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-workmanager

This is the code in my app_setting.dart file which has the logic to reset the habits, something that needs to be done every midnight even when the app is not up and running. I use Work Manager to execute the said task.

```
  /* ---- FUNCTION TO SCHEDULE HABIT RESET ---- */
  static void scheduleHabitReset() async {
    final userTimezone = await AppSettings.userTimeZone();

    // Define the frequency of the periodic task (daily at midnight)
    final taskFrequency = Duration(days: 1);

    final delayInSeconds = await secondsUntilMidnight();
    Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask(
      "habit_reset_task",
      "habit_reset",
      frequency: taskFrequency,
      initialDelay: Duration.zero, // Start immediately
      inputData: <String, dynamic>{},
    );
    print('habit reset has been executed Mr. CEO');
  }


  static Future<int> secondsUntilMidnight() async {
    final userTimezone = await AppSettings.userTimeZone(); // Wait for the result
    final now = TZDateTime.now(getLocation(userTimezone));
    final midnight = TZDateTime(now.location, now.year, now.month, now.day + 1);
    return midnight.millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000 - now.millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;
  }



  /* ---- FUNCTION TO RESET HABIT ITEMS ---- */
  static Future<void> resetHabits(Function() resetHabit) async {
    String userTimezone = await AppSettings.userTimeZone();
    final timeZone = getLocation(userTimezone);

    // Get the current time in the dynamically determined timezone
    final currentTime = TZDateTime.now(timeZone);

    // Calculate the time until midnight
    final midnight = TZDateTime(
        timeZone, currentTime.year, currentTime.month, currentTime.day + 1);

    // Calculate the duration until midnight
    final durationUntilMidnight = midnight.difference(currentTime);

    // Schedule the reset function to run at midnight
    Timer(durationUntilMidnight, () {
      resetHabit();

      // Schedule the reset again after 24 hours
      Timer(const Duration(hours: 24), resetHabit);
    });

    print("Waiting until midnight in $timeZone...");
  }
```

At home_tab.dart, we call the app setting in this way

```
  /* ---- FUNCTION TO INTIALISE RESET PROGRESS WHEN APP IS FIRST STARTED ---- */
  Future<void> _initialize() async {
    try {
      await AppSettings.resetHabits(() =>
          resetProgress()); // -----> Refer AppSettings file - this is where it resets at midnight and after 24 hours
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

The problem is it is not working. It does reset the habit, but only if the app isn't completely closed. I've tried to fix this for the past 2 days and can't seem to get it to work. Any thoughts?

I tried using work manager and it didn't work.